# independent/dependent values at different frequencies and phases

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am curious about the following problem. I would like to ask for help solving it.  Consider the following $m$ sinusoidal functions

$\sin(\omega_{1}⋅t+\phi_1),\sin(\omega_{2}⋅t+\phi_2),..., \sin(\omega_{m}⋅t+\phi_m)$

If we write it as a horizontal line and change $t$ from $1$ to $n$, we get $n \times m$ matrix where entries are values from sinusoidal function at different frequencies and phases, they are  not related to each other, in frequencies and phases, say, ratio of frequencies $w_i/w_j$ can be irrational.

Now if we allow $n=m$ or the matrix to be square, what is chance that the matrix is singular? What can we say about its eigenvalues and eigenvectors? At different  frequencies and  phases can columns or rows be dependent on each other?

If $n\neq m$, what can we say about the non-square matrix?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the complex version, square matrix $(e^{i\omega_jk})_{j,k=1}^n$ is singular iff $\omega_k-\omega_j=2q\pi$, for some $q\in\mathbf Z$ for each $(j,k)$. This can be shown using Vandermonde determinant. But I do not know how to get the similar property for the real and imaginary parts. I am very interested in this question, particularly when $t$ takes on arbitrary values, not just the integers $1,2,...,n$. Maybe you could try posting this question in mathoverflow.net. Please post a link here when you do, so I can follow.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/158358/independent-dependent-values-at-different-frequencies-and-phases

Comment: thanks a lot of,i need it and  created myself,it is not taken from any book

Comment: Does the complex version I mentioned in my comment help you in any way?

Comment: complex  makes sense,but  if we have euler formula,we can somehow represent  my form into complex one is not it?

Comment: but maybe there should be different case  when represent same  question using cosine function,because cosine represent as real part of euler  form and sin is just imaginary form

Comment: That is the goal of my complex version. The question is whether one could and how to convert the singularity of the complex version to the real (imaginary) one or vice versa.

Comment: Take a look at this mathoverflow.net question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/158433/when-is-this-matrix-singular/158466?noredirect=1#comment405554_158466 I set up. Someone has given a partial solution.

Comment: thanks very much for link,it seems nice,thanks my friend

Comment: i will keep this information,thanks that you remembered this question